# Getting a random draw from the binomial distribution based on a sample statistic

Tags: r, random, montecarlo

EDIT: rephrased question for clarity of what I was wanting to achieve.

I have an observed dataset from which I want to use some information to feed into a Monte Carlo simulation. I'm using R for this study.

e.g. 8/8 individuals have a particular characteristic in my observed dataset.

What I want to do is use the sampling distribution from this observed data  to choose some possible population proportions to feed into a random number generator, whereby I can then generate some simulated counts (where I also need to use a larger denominator).

The observed data and the 95% confidence interval are as follows:

```
binom.test(8, 8)
## gives point estimate of 1 and 95% CI 0.63, 1
```

I would then want to take (e.g.) 1000 random draws from this sampling distribution to feed into a random binary outcome generator for a larger denominator (e.g. 12 trials per iteration). Let’s say the first random draw was a 0.75 chance of having an event (code below is just illustrating a single iteration):

```
set.seed(456)    
rbinom(1, 12, 0.75)
## Gives a count of 11 events out of 12 for this single iteration.
```

My question then is how to get R to draw the probabilities from the observed data’s sampling distribution (i.e. 95% of these drawn probabilities should fall between 0.63 and 1, with a shape as defined by the underlying statistical theory), which I can then use to generate random counts with a larger denominator (probably using rbinom).

EDIT: My original post was more convoluted and confusing: I hadn’t fully thought through the implications of rbinom using a population parameter, even though I was pretty sure that this was the source of my "problem" with rbinom. Thanks to DavidRobinson and DWin for comments/answers that clarified my answer as well as my revised question...

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you would need a prior to do this (a commonly used prior for binomial sampling is `Beta(1, 1)`). It would then be updated using your evidence to a posterior probability distribution (in the case of the beta prior, this would be `Beta(8, 9)`). You could then sample your true population parameter from that. But the distribution would depend on your prior.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Thanks for the comment -- this got me on the right track and sent me to a book on Bayesian analysis. I'll post an answer when I've worked this through.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Thanks again, I've posted a worked implementation as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was developed out of a comment by @DavidRobinson (thanks!) who suggested making a posterior distribution of the probabilities that are plausible based on my observed data.

Code adapted p. 42 of Hoff, P.D. (2009), *A First Course in Bayesian Statistics*, Springer, NY.

```
## Set a uniform prior.
a <- 1; b <- 1
## Set observed data.
n <- 8; y <- 8

## Posterior 95% confidence interval:
qbeta(c(.025, .975), a+y, b+n-y)
## returns [1] 0.6637329 0.9971909
```

This is very close to the confidence interval based on the binomial distribution, slightly different due to influence of prior.

```
binom.test(8, 8)
## returns  95% CI of 0.6305834 1.0000000.
```

Now I can draw a set of random probabilities from this posterior distribution to use to generate some counts. I'll just use five draws here for illustration.

```
set.seed(9876)
n.draws <- 5

## Use rbeta to get n.draws from posterior distribution.
drawn.probs <- rbeta(n.draws, a+y, b+n-y)

## Now I can use these drawn probabilities in rbinom to get simulated counts.
rbinom(n.draws, 12, drawn.probs)
```

Thanks for comments/answers -- this made me realise that this wasn't just a problem I was having with trying to use rbinom, but that I was missing an intermediate step.

Comment: If you wanted to draw further samples from a distribution with a parameter at the lower bound of a 95% CI, ... then you should have said so. As it was, you were asking to draw from a distribution _at_ the observed binomial parameter ... a quite different request.

Comment: @DWin I've revised the question to try to make my aim clearer (please feel free to make further edits if you think still unclear) -- my apologies for the earlier confusion. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You are confused ... since your first question is nonsense ... and this is the wrong venue for this discussion. There are many theoretical populations that could plausibly and even implausibly give rise to an observed series of Bernoulli draws of 8/8  from a binomial population. Say you had 99 black balls and one white ball in an urn. It would be reasonably plausible to get 8/8 black balls in 8 draws with replacement. The probability of such a sequence would be (99/100)^8 = 0.923

This code sshow how this works in R "practice"

```
> set.seed(123)
> sum(rbinom(10000, 8, .99)==8)
[1] 9263
```

So in this simulation, 92.63% of 8 draw sequences had all 8 of the balls be black. Now rethink what you are asking and pose further such questions( at stats.stackexchange.

Comment: I'm not totally confused, although my question may well give that impression. I am aware that observing 8/8 trials is consistent with a range of possible population probabilities, as reflected in a confidence interval for the proportion (and also as illustrated by your example code.) What I would like to do is draw from that sampling distribution (of possible population values of the likelihood of an event), and apply those random draws to make some new simulated counts for a Monte Carlo setting. I'll try to edit my question later today to clarify.

Comment: The range of possible binomial distributions yielding 8/8 positive (or "all black") on a single sequential trial of 8 draws includes ones with very low proportions of black. If being done with replacement, even underlying probabilities with Pr(Black) = 0.01 _could_ result in all Black. So still I think you need to clarify in your mind what is being requested.

Comment: Thanks David. I didn't end up rewriting my question, but the scope of the problem may be clearer based on the answer I've added based on the advice of @DavidRobinson.